# Use SQL to assign id based on fields with duplicate values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Do to a mistake in data entry I need to change the value in a table based upon the value in another table. The best way to explain is by showing a "contrived example".

```
Site Table

SiteId       SiteName
----------------------
1            Chicago
2            New York
3            Boston
4            Chicago
5            New York
6            Boston

Project Table

ProjectName      SiteId
---------------------------
Project #1         1
Project #2         2
Project #3         2
Project #4         3
```

I need to update the Project Table to use the "second" set of `SiteId`s from the `Site` Table instead of the ones being used. For example, I need The Project Table to look like ...

```
ProjectName      SiteId
---------------------------
Project #1         4
Project #2         5
Project #3         5
Project #4         6
```

I originally thought of a self join but I am not sure how to differentiate between `SiteName` values. I can join using the `SiteName` but how can I make sure I assign the second set of `SiteId`s

The actual list is very long so I cannot do it by hand.

UPDATE: The Project Name's are unique and there is also a unique row identifier for the Project Table.

Comment: Are the ProjectName unique?

Comment: I don't see any relation between Projects Table and Site table apart from Site ID. What exactly is your logic to assign the "second" set of Site ID?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
UPDATE p
SET p.SiteId=s2.SiteId
FROM Project p
INNER JOIN Site s on s.SiteId=p.SiteId
INNER JOIN (
SELECT SiteName,MAX(SiteId) as SiteId 
FROM Site
GROUP BY SiteName) s2 on s2.SiteName=s.SiteName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE P 
SET SiteId = S.maxSiteId 
FROM Project P 
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(SiteId) AS maxSiteId,
                   MIN(SiteId) AS minSiteId
            FROM   Site 
            GROUP BY SiteName) S 
   ON P.SiteId = S.MinSiteId
```

Comment: Did you perhaps mean `GROUP BY SiteName`?